# Publishing issue in various languages

Tags: publishing

I publish some items in two languages(NZL and AUS) but when I came back to my US site i found that those items were not found in US site..Any idea why did this happen?
Appreciate with examples or any link would be helpful too.

Comment: i think you to complete your problem statement. Add more details. Did those items were part of US site & went missing just after publishing ? More info would be appreiciated.

Comment: First thing first, please provide more details. Did you check on the target database if the items are there? Also, if the item are not being shown on the US site, the most probable issue is due to the context language. If the US site is using en-US and the items are not in en-US version, they will not appear.

Comment: Actually I published some items from AUD and NZD sites that has publishing target to one WEB DB so by mistake Config team has published the whole folder but due to that publishing Items got deleted from US sites...how is it possible?I hope you got my point now

Comment: I sit probably due to Publishing Restrcition?

Comment: If you have publish restriction on the item and perform a publish, it will remove the item from the target database. Check if the item which are not available on the target database has restriction on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a US Site which I assume is in language `en-US` and you are publishing 2 languages (NZL and AUS). The reason why the published item will not be available on the US Site is because of the context language of the site. The US Site will only load items which have a version in the `en-US` language.

Based on this comment

> Actually I published some items from AUD and NZD sites that has
>   publishing target to one WEB DB so by mistake Config team has
>   published the whole folder but due to that publishing Items got
>   deleted from US sites

The main reason why the items for the US Site got disappear is due to the Publish Restriction. The Publish Restriction will remove the items from the Target Database if set.

You can directly see on the item if there is a publish restriction set on it if you have `unchecked` the Publishable checkbox from the **Item Tab** of the Publish Restriction.

[image]

If you have 2 Databases in the **Target Tab** and only 1 is selected, the item will only be published to the selected one and get removed from the other one. When this is *activated*, it will not show any warnings like the one for **Item Tab**.

Comment: Yeah correct...Thanks! for the info and I figured  out same thing.